# Django db back up postgres error

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models, django-orm

I am using django-dbbackup to create a backup of my *postgres db*. When I run `python manage.py dbbackup` it creates a `default.backup` file.

But, when I run `python manage.py dbrestore` I get the following error.

```
Restoring backup for database: hera
 Finding latest backup
 Restoring: /home/dev/Documents/Program Codes/Python/Django/Hera/default.backup
 Restore tempfile created: 670.5 KB
 Are you sure you want to continue? [Y/n]y
 Running: dropdb --username=****** --host=localhost hera
 dropdb: database removal failed: ERROR:  must be owner of database hera

CommandError: Error running: [u'dropdb', u'--username=dev', u'--host=localhost', u'hera']
```

Comment: Seems a clear message: `dropdb: database removal failed: ERROR:  must be owner of database hera`

Comment: But, how do I run it as the owner?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is about making sure the user you're using is the owner of the database. Right now it looks like you're running the `dbrestore` command using the `dev` user (from the line `CommandError: Error running: [u'dropdb', u'--username=dev', u'--host=localhost', u'hera']`).

There are likely three options:

1/ Change the owner of the database to `dev` using a PSQL command something like:

```
ALTER DATABASE hera OWNER TO dev;
```

2/ Change the `--username=dev` your dbrestore script uses when it runs to the owner of the database (something other than `dev`, you can use `\l` in PSQL to list your databases and see which user owns the database.

3/ You could give `dev` superuser and createdb ability, though not sure this is ideal in terms of security.